# Gramaticalmente, ¿qué diferencia hay entre "super-" y "sobre-" con el sentido de "exceso"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, prefijos

Dándole todavía vueltas al tema de los elementos compositivos, me encuentro con que tenemos dos que provienen del mismo prefijo del latín:

- *[Sobre-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y5mVN6j)*: Indica intensificación o exceso.
- *[Super-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YidtEBo)*: Significa 'en grado sumo' o 'exceso'.

Es cierto que ambas tienen otras acepciones, pero la duda me surge cuando ambas se emplean en el sentido de "exceso". Así, se puede decir que algo está "supercaliente" cuando está excesivamente caliente, pero la acción de poner algo supercaliente no es *supercalentar*, sino *sobrecalentar* ([10 casos](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=sobrecalent*&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) de este último en el CORDE contra [1 caso](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=supercalent*&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) del primero; en el CREA son [87 casos](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=0&texto=sobrecalent*&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) contra ninguno).

En principio parece que se podría decir que "super-" precede a los adjetivos, mientras que "sobre-" precede a los verbos. ¿Es esto así? ¿Cuál es gramaticalmente la diferencia entre ambos? ¿Cuándo se debe usar cada uno? ¿Depende del tipo de palabra que venga después, o cada caso depende de su propia evolución en el lenguaje? ¿Y ante sustantivos, tiene sentido usar alguno de los dos en el sentido de "exceso"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Super-* es más productivo y más coloquial que *sobre-*; probablemente esas dos cosas estén relacionadas (es en el habla coloquial donde aparecen la mayoría de los neologismos). *Supercaliente*, *supercansado*, *superaburrido* son todas palabras que expresan coloquialmente una intensificación más enfática que la de un *muy*. Puede funcionar con sustantivos si refieren claramente a ciertas cualidades, y en particular con sustantivos que derivan directamente de adjetivos.

Como dice Carlos, *super-* en este sentido tiende a ser sustituido por *sobre-* en los verbos, pero aparte de *supercaliente* vs. *sobrecalentar* sólo pude pensar en otro par contrastante: *superabundancia* vs. *sobreabundar*.

En el registro coloquial, en mi dialecto, tampoco es tan raro ver *super-* con verbos, aunque la prosodia oscila entre usarlo como prefijo y como adverbio separable. Quiero decir: yo escucho cosas como *Se súper enojó con él* o *Le súper cortó el rostro*; el prefijo todavía no está bien integrado. Aquí se trata de un énfasis o de un exceso, según el caso.

Con sustantivos el uso de *super-* con el sentido de "exceso" es también coloquial: *Es un superidiota, un supertarado, un superpayaso; pasé una supervergüenza por su culpa, me sentí una supertonta.* Aquí también lo escucho separado a veces, o quizá sea un acento tónico secundario lo que me lo sugiere.

Otro uso de *super-* es en términos técnicos como *supersaturado* o *supersimetría*, pero no hablamos de esto, creo (algo *supersaturado* no está "muy saturado", y una *supersimetría* es una simetría de nivel superior, no una cosa "muy simétrica").

En cuanto a *sobre-*, el uso en el sentido de "exceso" es más restringido porque *sobre-* remite a la preposición homónima en el sentido de posición (*sobrevolar*) o bien a un sentido positivo de "superación" (*sobrellevar*). Ya *sobrecalentar* es un término casi formal/técnico (¿quién dice *Esta agua está sobrecalentada*?) y ni hablar de *sobreabundar*. Los otros verbos con *sobre-* tienen otro significado: *sobrevivir*, *sobrepasar*, *sobrellevar*, etc. no implican exceso. De los verbos donde *sobre-* tiene el significado de exceso y que sean de uso común se me ocurren *sobrecargar*, *sobresalir*, *sobreestimar* y *sobrevender*; nótese cómo de varios de ellos derivan sustantivos comunes: *sobrecarga*, *sobreestimación*, *sobreventa*, todos excepciones a la "regla" de que los sustantivos llevan *super-*. Otros sustantivos que llevan *sobre-* lo emplean con el sentido de "cosa puesta sobre otra" (*sobretodo*, *sobrecubierta*, *sobrehueso*).

Este panorama variado es lo que puedo aportar como respuesta aproximada, a la que espero alguien pueda contribuir.

Comment: Me parece una respuesta muy acertada. Solo un apunte: palabras como "idiota", "tarado", "payaso" y "tonta", que afirmas que son sustantivos, en realidad son adjetivos que, según la RAE, pueden ser usados también como sustantivos. Así que en realidad estamos ante el caso inicial de usar "sobre-" con adjetivos. El único caso de sustantivo real es el que comentas de la "supervergüenza" ("vergüenza en exceso", buen ejemplo).

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Muy cierto. Se me ocurren también *superbronca* y otras más malsonantes. Están en el límite: son énfasis, no indicadores de exceso propiamente.

Comment: Muy buena la respuesta, Pablo. Me parece que la diferencia clave entre "súper" y "sobre" es que la primera intensifica lo positivo o negativo de la palabra que sigue mientras que la segunda siempre indica "más de lo que corresponde/conviene" (salvo en los casos donde indica ubicación).